# How to compare 2 non-identical dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert

I have two dataframes with the same column order but different column names and different rows. `df2` rows vary from `df1` rows.

```
df1=     col_id  num  name
      0   1     3     linda
      1   2     4     James

df2=     id     no   name
      0   1     2    granpa
      1   2     6    linda
      2   3     7    sam
```

This is the output I need. Outputs rows with same, OLD and NEW values so the user can clearly see what changed between two dataframes:

```
 result   col_id        num              name   
      0   1             was 3| now 2    was linda| now granpa  
      1   2             was 4| now 6    was James| now linda
      2   was  | now 3  was  | now 7    was      | now sam
```

Comment: Why nans in the middle?

Comment: @user17242583 - sorry about that. I have corrected my question . Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is just to compare differences, use **[`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)** instead of aggregating into strings.

However,

> [`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) can only compare identically-labeled (i.e. same shape, identical row and column labels) DataFrames

So we just need to align the row/column indexes, either via [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

---

#### Align via [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

1. Outer-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dfs:

   ```
   merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on='col_id', right_on='id')
   #    col_id  num  name_x  id  no  name_y
   # 0       1    3   linda   1   2  granpa
   # 1       2    4   james   2   6   linda
   # 2     NaN  NaN     NaN   3   7     sam
   ```
2. Divide the `merged` frame into `left`/`right` frames and align their columns with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

   ```
   cols = df1.columns
   left = merged.iloc[:, :len(cols)].set_axis(cols, axis=1)
   #    col_id  num    name
   # 0       1    3   linda
   # 1       2    4   james
   # 2     NaN  NaN     NaN

   right = merged.iloc[:, len(cols):].set_axis(cols, axis=1)
   #    col_id  num    name
   # 0       1    2  granpa
   # 1       2    6   linda
   # 2       3    7     sam
   ```
3. [`compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) the aligned `left`/`right` frames (use `keep_equal=True` to show equal cells):

   ```
   left.compare(right, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
   #        col_id         num          name
   #    self other  self other   self  other
   # 0     1     1     3     2  linda granpa
   # 1     2     2     4     6  james  linda
   # 2   NaN     3   NaN     7    NaN    sam

   left.compare(right, keep_shape=True)
   #        col_id         num          name
   #    self other  self other   self  other
   # 0   NaN   NaN     3     2  linda granpa
   # 1   NaN   NaN     4     6  james  linda
   # 2   NaN     3   NaN     7    NaN    sam
   ```

---

#### Align via [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

If you are 100% sure that one df is a subset of the other, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the subsetted rows.

In your example, `df1` is a subset of `df2`, so [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df1`:

```
df1.assign(id=df1.col_id)          # copy col_id (we need original col_id after reindexing)
   .set_index('id')                # set index to copied id
   .reindex(df2.id)                # reindex against df2's id
   .reset_index(drop=True)         # remove copied id
   .set_axis(df2.columns, axis=1)  # align column names
   .compare(df2, keep_equal=True, keep_shape=True)

#        col_id         num          name
#    self other  self other   self  other
# 0     1     1     3     2  linda granpa
# 1     2     2     4     6  james  linda
# 2   NaN     3   NaN     7    NaN    sam
```

---

#### Nullable integers

Normally `int` cannot mix with `nan`, so pandas converts to `float`. To keep the `int` values as `int` (like the examples above):

- Ideally we'd convert the `int` columns to [nullable integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) with `astype('Int64')` (capital `I`).
- However, there is currently a [comparison bug with `Int64`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43038), so just use `astype(object)` for now.

Comment: you are a genius. Beautiful description and thanks so much for taking time to understand my problem and provide the solution. I later realized my columns vary and not the rows so I had to tweak a little bit and get 2 dataframes to be same but your solution is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```py
new_df = df1.drop(['name', 'num'], axis=1).merge(df2.rename({'id': 'col_id'}, axis=1), how='outer')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   col_id  no    name
0       1   2  granpa
1       2   6   linda
2       3   7     sam
```

Comment: Thanks @user17242583, I am trying to compare and capture  the difference  between df1 and df2 for the user.